# Magento2 : How to use default captcha code in footer newsletter?

Tags: magento2, captcha

How to validate user entered captcha and image captcha validation.

Comment: yes it is duplicate but i want to use this captcha at newsletter form.

Comment: You may use this  free plugin https://amasty.com/google-invisible-recaptcha-for-magento-2.html

also documentation is here you need to add your form class so it will show recaptcha https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_2:google_invisible-recaptcha-m2#general_settings

Comment: i have used google captcha it's working fine but i need to use default captcha of magento2 so i'm trying for that.

Comment: in case if you want to try https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html

Comment: @Sarfaraj, Are you able to display captcha in the newsletter form?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Yes , i got captcha in footer newsletter column.

Comment: @Sarfaraj How you have done this?

Comment: @AmritPalSingh, No till not did it.