# Add Captcha to magento 2 contact form on cms page

Tags: magento2.2.4, contact-form, captcha

I have to add captcha on the contact form. It's working on the default contact URL but not working with the contact form on CMS page.

```
<p>{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}</p>

<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
<block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
    <action method="setFormId">
        <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">contact_us</argument>
    </action>
    <action method="setImgWidth">
        <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
    </action>
    <action method="setImgHeight">
        <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
    </action>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
<referenceBlock name="head.components">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="captcha_page_head_components" template="Magento_Captcha::js/components.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Please give me some suggestion or help.

Comment: Paste the code you have added on your cms page?

Comment: @magecode, please try my answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to call **`<p>{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}</p>`** in the content tab.

If you don't have any other content to show in the content tab, then you can use **`&nbsp;`** in the Content tab.

Steps to show captcha in contact form in CMS page are listed below:

**Step 1:** Open the CMS page in which you want to show the contact form with captcha and click on the Design tab.

**Step 2:** Paste the following code in the Layout Update XML textarea:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
        <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info">
            <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
                <action method="setFormId">
                    <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">contact_us</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgWidth">
                    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgHeight">
                    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </container>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
<referenceBlock name="head.components">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="captcha_page_head_components" template="Magento_Captcha::js/components.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Step 3:** Save the page.

**Note:** After form submission, the page will redirect to default contact page. If you want to change it then override the controller.

Comment: Yes it's working but now I am getting error with overridden controller 
Call to a member function send() on null

With line $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());

Comment: I am getting data in this $post array

private function sendEmail($post) {
        print_r($post);
        $this->mail->send($post['email'], ['data' => new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($post)]);
    }

Comment: If my answer to the current question is working, please upvote my answer and ask this question as a different question in detail. From the comment it is hard to understand the details.

Comment: I have posted new question please check

Comment: @Magecode, please post URL here so that I can find it easily.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232501/contact-post-controller-overridden-in-custom-module-not-working

Comment: how to call this captcha in footer newsletter and check captcha value and entered value of captcha is same or not...?

Comment: Hi @Sarfaraj, your question is not related to this one. Please ask a new question since it is related to a different form. You can refer to this question if you like.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora  please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209575/magento2-how-to-use-default-captcha-code-in-newsletter

i want to check CAPTCHA in controller with captcha value and user entered value

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define the prepare layout under the block class

   protected function _prepareLayout () {
   $this->addChild(
   'msp-recaptcha',
   \MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha::class)
   ->setTemplate("MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml")
   ->setJsLayout(['components' => ['msp-recaptcha' => ['component' => 'MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha', 'zone' => 'career_form']]]);
   parent:: _prepareLayout();
   }
2. Than under the .phtml
   just use

   getChildHtml('msp-recaptcha') ?>