# Magento 2 show captcha at contact us form block section

Tags: magento2, cms-block, captcha, contact-form

I use below code to show cms block in cms page
`{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}`

Answer (score 0):

To Show captcha on the contact form, you need to enable and select contact form from admin configurations.

Show CAPTHA to a Contact Us form you have to go to  Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customers Configuration page and Enable CAPTCHA.

Comment: I enable captcha but it works only page not block section

Comment: Please check this Answer, May it will help you. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232435/add-captcha-to-magento-2-contact-form-on-cms-page