# captcha for a contact formular

Tags: contact-form, captcha

I use a contactformular in my magento shop https://agoshop.at/kontakt
The problem is that I will get very day up to 4 an more dummy contact informations. I think I will need there a captcha in this form to check if the user is a human.
I will check my backend and find a site contact with the following content:

```
<p><strong>{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}</strong></p>
```

I find a form.phtml file in the folder \vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\templates
with the following content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm $block */
?>
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Us')) ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.')) ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Wie können wir Ihnen behilflich sein?')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"><?= $block->escapeHtml($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So I think this is the correct file but how can I add a captcha?
Hope someone can help me there.
kindly regards

Comment: Is using https://agoshop.at/contact instead and removing that /kontakt page (and redirect /kontakt to /contact if needed) an option?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I didn't notice that it will forward to contact. I have changed it. It works now fine.
kindly regards

Comment: I noticed now an other small problem. The text infront of the textbox for the captcha is not complete: Here a picture of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytke7524qlnu9tl/contact_captcha.png?dl=0
Hope someone has still a solution. KIndly regards

Comment: You probably want to check out this duplicate in regard to the captcha in cms pages: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232487/34469
In regard to your label-issue: You've got some nasty width definition on `.fieldset > .field:not(.choice) > .label` and `.fieldset > .field:not(.choice) > .control` (width is fixed to 25.8% resp 74.2% and floating) hence your overlapping

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you informe me in which file I can find the settings of the wrong width.
Also I cannot find it in any menu in the magento backend.
kindly regards again.

Comment: Impossible from outside. It's compiled into https://agoshop.at/pub/static/frontend/smart_media/smart_media1/de_DE/css/styles-l.css which suggests that the style defintion in question is located in _any_ .less file. 25.8% resp 74.2% however (if not calculated) sounds rather 'unique', meaning, you should be able to find it by grep'ing your source or use a 'search in all files' function on your IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It looks like fine. What do you think?
kindly regards

Comment: Hi!
I have still one more question.
Is it also possible to add the captcha direct in my https://agoshop.at/kontakt site.
kindly regards again.

Answer (score 0):

I have find now an instruction to activate captcha also for a contact form.
https://ccbill.com/kb/magento-contact-captcha
When I want to send a new message via the contactform and after I press the button I will get a message to insert a captcha. I don't see the captcha before.
So I want ask if it is possible to see the captcha already when I open the contact formular.
kindly regards for any answer